# Удаление NSBezierPath

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

Создаю полигон mainPath (NSBezierPath). Отдельно от основного "пути" есть еще один NSBezierPath. Его назвал guidLine (серая направляющая линия, создается от последней добавленной (кликом мыши) точки до места положения курсора. По завершению построения объекта (назначил через F5) через [mainPath closePath], полигон замыкается с последней точки на первую. Остается направляющая линия. Как ее удалить? Т.е. завершить построение объекта (полигона). Проще говоря, мне нужно удалить guidLine. Возможно ли это и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придется вызвать перерисовку всего view, на котором уже отрисовывать только то, что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо что отклинулись. Сделал по другому, через булевую переменную и условие. Т.е. при создании объекта булевая принимает ТРУ, и рисуется гайдлайн-направляющая, иначе не рисуется (по завершению объекта).